# Void function to compute the weight of the node pointed at

Tags: c++, data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I need to write a void function which can compute the number of nodes in each subtree.
i read a lot of sample code but they all return an integer.  And i dont know how to use a non-recursive void function to do the same function as those int function.

This is what i have so far:

```
void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p)
{
//compute the weight of the node pointed at by p    
//weight of a node is equal to the number of nodes in the correspodning subtree
if(p == NULL)
    p->info.weight = 0;
else
    p->info.weight = 1 + p->left->info.weight + p->right->info.weight;
//note that this is not a recursive function
}
```

this is the struct of treeInfo:

```
struct treeInfo
{   
char symb;
int weight;
};
```

this is the binaryTree.h which is a normal binary tree header

```
template<class Type>
struct treeNode
{
Type info;
treeNode<Type> *left;
treeNode<Type> *right;
};
template<class Type>
class treeIterator
{
protected:
treeNode<Type> *current;
stack<treeNode<Type>*> s;

public:
treeIterator(treeNode<Type> *p)
{
    current = NULL;

    while (p != NULL)
    {
        s.push(p);
        p = p->left;
    }

    if (!s.empty())
    {
        current = s.top();
        s.pop();
    }
}

treeIterator(const treeIterator<Type>& other)
{
    current = other.current;
    s = other.s;
}

Type& operator*() 
{   return current->info;  }


treeIterator<Type>& operator++()  //pre-increment operator
{
    if (current != NULL)
    {
        current = current->right;
        while (current != NULL)
        {
            s.push(current);
            current = current->left;
        }
        if (!s.empty())
        {
            current = s.top();
            s.pop();
        }
    }
    else
        cerr << "Error: treeIterator gets out of bound" << endl;

    return *this;
}

bool operator==(const treeIterator<Type>& other)
{  return current == other.current;  }

bool operator!=(const treeIterator<Type>& other)
{  return current != other.current;  }

};

template<class Type>
class binaryTree
{
protected:
treeNode<Type> *root;

public:
binaryTree()
{   root = NULL; }

binaryTree(const binaryTree<Type>& other);
~binaryTree();

const binaryTree<Type>& operator=(const binaryTree<Type>& other);

bool empty()
{   return root == NULL;  }

int height();
int nodeCount();
int leavesCount();

void inorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *));
void preorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *));
void postorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *));

void destroy();

treeIterator<Type> begin();
treeIterator<Type> end();

void print(int inc);
void buildTreeFromArray(Type a[], int n, Type nullSymbol);  

private:
treeNode<Type>* copyTree(const treeNode<Type> *other);
void destroy(treeNode<Type> *p);
int height(treeNode<Type> *p);
int nodeCount(treeNode<Type> *p);
int leavesCount(treeNode<Type> *p);
void inorder(treeNode<Type> *p, void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *));
void postorder(treeNode<Type> *p, void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *));

void printTree(const treeNode<Type> *p, int indent, int inc);
treeNode<Type>* buildTree(Type a[], int n, int i, Type nullSymbol);
};

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::preorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *p))
{
//implement a non-recrusive preorder traversal of the binary tree
stack<treeNode<Type>*> stack_tree;

stack_tree.push(root);
treeNode<Type> *p = root;
while(!stack_tree.empty())
{
    treeNode<Type>* temp = stack_tree.top();
    (*visit)(temp);

    stack_tree.pop();
    if(temp ->right)
        stack_tree.push(temp ->right);
    if(temp ->left)
        stack_tree.push(temp ->left);
}
} 

template<class Type>
treeNode<Type>* binaryTree<Type>::buildTree(Type a[], int n, int i, Type nullSymbol)
{
treeNode<Type> *p = NULL;

if (i < n && a[i] != nullSymbol)
{
    p = new treeNode<Type>;
    p->info = a[i];
    p->left = buildTree(a, n, 2*i+1, nullSymbol);
    p->right = buildTree(a, n, 2*(i+1), nullSymbol);
}

return p;
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::buildTreeFromArray(Type a[], int n, Type nullSymbol)
{
root = buildTree(a, n, 0, nullSymbol);
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::printTree(const treeNode<Type> *p, int indent, int inc)
{
if (p != NULL)
{
    printTree(p->right, indent+inc, inc);
    cout << setw(indent) << p->info << endl;
    printTree(p->left, indent+inc, inc);
}
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::print(int inc)
{
printTree(root, 4, inc);
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::height(treeNode<Type> *p) 
{
if (p == NULL)
    return 0;
int HL = height(p->left);
int HR = height(p->right);
if (HL >= HR)
    return 1+HL;
else
    return 1+HR;
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::height()  
{
return height(root);
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::nodeCount(treeNode<Type> *p)  
{
if (p == NULL)
    return 0;

return 1 + nodeCount(p->left) + nodeCount(p->right);
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::nodeCount()  
{
return nodeCount(root);
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::leavesCount(treeNode<Type> *p)  
{
if (p == NULL)
    return 0;

if (p->left == NULL && p->right == NULL)
    return 1;

return leavesCount(p->left) + leavesCount(p->right);
}

template<class Type>
int binaryTree<Type>::leavesCount()  
{
return leavesCount(root);
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::inorder(treeNode<Type> *p, void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *))
{
if (p != NULL)
{
    inorder(p->left, visit);
    (*visit)(p);
    inorder(p->right, visit);
}
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::postorder(treeNode<Type> *p, void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *))
{
if (p != NULL)
{
    postorder(p->left, visit);      
    postorder(p->right, visit);
    (*visit)(p);
}
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::inorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *))
{
inorder(root, visit);
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::postorderTraversal(void (*visit)(treeNode<Type> *))
{
postorder(root, visit);
}

template<class Type>
treeNode<Type>* binaryTree<Type>::copyTree(const treeNode<Type> *other)
{
    if (other == NULL)
    return NULL;

treeNode *p = new treeNode<Type>;
p->info = other->info;
p->left = copyTree(other->left);
p->right = copyTree(other->right);
}

template<class Type>
binaryTree<Type>::binaryTree(const binaryTree<Type>& other)
{
root = copyTree(other.root);
}

template<class Type>
const binaryTree<Type>& binaryTree<Type>::operator=(const binaryTree<Type>& other)
{
if (this != &other)
{
    destroy(root);
    root = copyTree(other.root);
}
}

template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::destroy(treeNode<Type> *p)
{
if (p != NULL)
{
    destroy(p->left);
    destroy(p->right);
    delete p;
}
}


template<class Type>
void binaryTree<Type>::destroy()
{
destroy(root);
root = NULL;
}


template<class Type>
binaryTree<Type>::~binaryTree()
{
destroy(root);
}


template<class Type>
treeIterator<Type> binaryTree<Type>::begin()
{
return treeIterator<Type>(root);
}

template<class Type>
treeIterator<Type> binaryTree<Type>::end()
{
return treeIterator<Type>(NULL);
}

#endif
```

Comment: Do you notice the similarity between the prototype of your function and the one that you gave to the argument for the "traversal" functions? You should probably take advantage of that similarity.

Comment: Does it have to be `void`? Is there a requirement to not return any data?

Comment: @molbdnilo you mean use the traversal function to help do the counting?

Comment: @EvanTeran It have to be void since the function declaration is given by my teacher

Comment: @RukaTsoi Exactly. See my answer below. (Part of it left as an exercise ;-)

Comment: You have to explain why you want the function to be `void` and why you don’t want to use recursion. Neither requirement make sense in context. (EDIT: okay, noticed your comment saying that the teacher gave the prototype. Still, the answer is to use a non-`void` function and then just call that from within your given function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all,

```
if(p == NULL)
    p->info.weight = 0;
```

is asking for trouble - you're not allowed to dereference `NULL`.

What you *should* do is something like this:

```
void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p)
{
    if (p != NULL)
    {
        int leftWeight = p->left != NULL ? p->left->info.weight : 0;
        int rightWeight = p->right != NULL ? p->right->info.weight : 0;
        p->info.weight = 1 + leftWeight + rightWeight;
    }
}
```

and take advantage of a traversal that ensures that the weights of the subtrees are computed first.
Since it's already implemented you only need to pick the right one.

---

Using it should look something like this

```
binaryTree<treeInfo> tree;
// ...  
// build the tree
// ...
tree.someTraversal(computeWeight);
// The weights are now computed.
```

Comment: when i run my program, all weights shown are equal to 1...it seems like there is no update of the leftweight and rightweight

Comment: @RukaTsoi Are you sure you're not accidentally working with a copy of the tree? (Updated with example call.)

Comment: i have added the function call in my main function
bt.preorderTraversal(computeWeight);
given that bt is a binaryTree<treeInfo>

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
 void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p)
 {    
     std::list<treeNode<treeInfo>*> nodesToVisit;
     std::list<treeNode<treeInfo>*> nodesVisited;

     nodesToVisit.push_back(p);

     while(!nodesToVisit.empty())
     {
        treeNode<treeInfo>* parent = nodesToVisit.front();
        nodesToVisit.pop_front();


        if (parent->left != NULL)
           nodesToVisit.push_back(parent->left);

        if (parent->right != NULL)
           nodesToVisit.push_back(parent->right);

        nodesVisited.push_back(parent);
     }

     int numberOfNodes = nodesVisited.size();
  }
```

I'm not sure about the efficiency of this but it's a void function that computes the number of nodes in each subtree.

Comment: list<treeNode<treeInfo>*> nodesToVisit;
what do the "list" mean?

Comment: It's a container in the C++ standard library (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/). I use it to store the nodes I have to visit. Once I deal with the nodes, I pass them to the nodesVisited list.

Answer (score 0):

Is it **allowed** to be recursive? If so, I think i can be as simple as this:

```
void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p) {
    //compute the weight of the node pointed at by p    
    //weight of a node is equal to the number of nodes in the corresponding sub-tree
    if(p) {
        // compute the weights of both children first
        computeWeight(p->left);
        computeWeight(p->right);

        // compute the weight of this node, taking into account its children
        int l_weight = p ? p->left->info.weight: 0;
        int r_weight = p ? p->right->info.weight: 0;
        p->info.weight = 1 + l_weight + r_weight;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to

- *use* recursion, and
- *use* an integer return type.

It will be completely analogous to the (already existing) `binaryTree<Type>::height` implementation.

Then you can call that function from within your non-recursive, `void` returning function and do … whatever with the result.

```
void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p) {
    int weight = getWeight(p);
    // Do something with it.
}

int getWeight(treeNode<treeInfo>* p) {
    return p == nullptr ? 0 : p->weight + getWeight(p->left) + getWeight(p->right);
}
```

Of course if the **specific** aim of the exercise is to solve this non-recursively then that solution won’t do – you have to emulate the recursion using a manually managed stack. Since you have the `treeIterator` I doubt that though – the iterator makes it both trivial and a pointless exercise:

```
void computeWeight(treeNode<treeInfo> *p) {
    using iterator = treeIterator<treeInfo>;
    int weight const = std::accumulate(iterator{p}, iterator{nullptr}, 0,
            [](int acc, treeNode<treeInfo>* n) { return acc + n->weight; });
}
```

A few notes on the code.

The code uses C++11 which should be standard in teaching since it makes the language vastly easier and safer, has been around for two years now, and is (to the extent used here) implemented in all modern compilers. However, knowing the quality of programming lessons, it may well be the case that you’re not supposed to use C++11 yet. In that case, complain to the teacher (I mean it!) and rewrite the above code – the changes are trivial except for the lambda. More about this:

My code uses an algorithm (`std::accumulate`) rather than a loop. There’s a consensus that this is ᴛʜᴇ ʀɪɢʜᴛ ᴛʜɪɴɢ™ since it abstracts away irrelevant details, and should be taught foremost and early in C++. But again that’s idealistic and probably not the case. It can be replaced by a loop easily enough:

```
int weight{};
for (iterator i{p}, end{}; i != end; ++i)
    weight += n->weight;
```

Wow, that’s even shorter. But it’s worse for a number of reasons, among them the fact that we can no longer make `weight` a `const`.

Finally, why do I recommend using recursion? – Because it’s conceptually vastly easier and almost certainly more efficient. Sure, it’s prone to stack overflows in theory. However, in practice it requires a *huge* (or extremely degenerate) tree to trigger a stack overflow here. It’s certainly not unheard of, and a robust general-purpose library would avoid it here, but for most practical applications it’s entirely acceptable.